# PowerBuilder GUI to web application - best options?

Tags: powerbuilder

Does anyone have any opinions on the best options for converting a PB GUI application that I sell to users to be a web app? (The web app would be run on my servers, not the clients' servers.)

It seems there are a number of options. One is to use PB 11's ability to retarget an app as an ASP.NET WebForms app, but I really don't understand yet what its limitations are.

Then there is Sybase's solution, Appeon.

And then there are a host of companies that do conversions to either .NET or Java web solutions, including Metex, BluePhoenix, EwakSoft, MainTrend, TeamCTI, Nexaweb, ...

Answer (score 2):

Go with Appeon if you have existing large size or PFC application.  It is easier to migrate.  If you are writing a new application, PB11.5 WebForm is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you don't get that many answers shows the declining of powerbuilder. Powerbuilder is now very exclusive to those who possess advance knowledge of programming. It is no longer for the newbees and not even for those with intermediate skills. The learning curve has become too steep for any newcomers. This is scary if you are thinking about maintaining these applications long term.

Comment: Or, this indicates that there are only two basic options to convert an existing PowerBuilder app to a web app. (There *are* other rewrite options.) As for "advance knowledge" and "steep learning curve", if anything PB has been and continues to be *too* easy to learn, resulting in people that have no business behind a keyboard and couldn't program their out of a paper "Hello World" bag being able to produce "results" that don't stand up. In other languages, they wouldn't have gotten past "Hello". (Not being able to produce basics, they never get a chance to write a bad logical unit of work.)